# Create directory/directories in Eclipse with java.io.File

Tags: java, eclipse, file, io, directory

I tried to make it as easy as possible.

**Example:**

```
File  f = new File("non_existing_dir/someDir");
System.out.println(f.mkdir());
System.out.println(f.mkdirs());
```

`mkdir()` and `mkdirs()` return both `false` °_°. Both work (create directory) if i use double backslash `\\` (like `"\\non_existing_dir\\someDir"`  BUT:

if I do `.toURI()` after that I receive: `file:/Users/MyName/Desktop/%5Cnon_existing_dir%5CsomeDir/`

if I do `.getPath()` i receive: `\non_existing_dir\someDir`

if I do `.getCanonicalPath()` I receive: `/Users/MyName/Desktop/\non_existing_dir\someDir`

So i want to have instead this results:

with `.toURI()` receiving: `file:/Users/MyName/Desktop`**`/non_existing_dir/someDir/`**

with `.getPath()` receiving: **`/non_existing_dir/someDir`**

and with `.getCanonicalPath()` receiving: `/Users/MyName/Desktop`**`/non_existing_dir/someDir`**

Thanks in advance to everyone.

Comment: a platform independent way would be to use `File.separator`.

Comment: I'm using Linux 12. It's giving the output as you expected

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `non_existing_dir` does not exists, you can check [`getParentFile()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html#getParentFile()) and create it with [`mkdir()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html#mkdir()).

Also avoid problems between OS with [`File.separator`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html#separator).

```
String filename = "non_existing_dir"  + File.separator + "someDir";

File  f = new File(filename);
if (!f.exists()) {
    if (!f.getParentFile().exists()) {
         // make the dir
         f.getParentFile().mkdir();
    }
    f.mkdir();
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much :-) It works now. And thanks to others that commented on my Question so quickly as well.